# Kubernetes ingress controller same path multiple ports

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

I have an application in node js that expose 2 ports, 80 for web and 5000 for a notification service with websockets.
I want to deploy in azure kubernetes service and I followed the tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-tls.
Everything works fine but websockets don't.

This is the yaml of the ingress controller:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: dih-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - www.mydomain.com
    secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
  - host: www.mydomain.com
    http:
      paths:
            
      - path: /(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: dihkub-9865
            port:
              number: 80
```

And this is the port configuration in the service yaml:

```
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
    - name: websocket
      protocol: TCP
      port: 5000
      targetPort: 5000
  selector:
    app: dihkub-9865
  clusterIP: 10.0.147.128
  type: ClusterIP
```

I am new to this and sorry for my bad english, thanks

Edit:
This is the new yaml file of the ingress controller

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: dih-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt

 
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - www.mydomain.com
    
    secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
  - host: www.mydomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /socket.io/(.*)
        backend:
          service: 
            name: dihkub-9865
            port: 
              number: 5000
      - path: /(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: dihkub-9865
            port:
              number: 80
```

Requests with the url /socket.io/ return error 502, now I put the services with loadbalancer so now I have 2 public IPs, the ingress controller handles requests to port 80 and the service handles requests from the websocket . This is not right but for now it works :(

Although the certificate with which the websockets work is not valid, since they do not work with the domain configured in the ingress controller, and having 2 public IPs is a bit more expensive.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need something like:

```
      - path: /websockets
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: dihkub-9865
            port:
              number: 5000
```

Or whatever path you want to use for the websockets server.

Comment: It doesn´t work, the base path of the websockets is /soket.io/ and when I add that path to the ingress controller it returns error 502

Comment: That means your pods for that service are probably not in a Ready state.

Comment: The PODS are active, the requests to port 80 work, but the requests to port 5000 do not work, try to test each service with loadbalancer and in that case it works but I need to use an ingress controller for the TLS certificates

Comment: I don't understand your comment, if you have a new question you might want to open that separately.